# Scroll view is scrolling when I don't want

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I made view which contains UIScrollView and imageViews. User can move these imageViews by pan gesture and when user finish panning I check if center point of panning view is in scroll view, if YES I add this panned View as subview to scroll view. Below is my code :

```
    - (void)checkPinsWithPanningView:(HSLabelView *)panningView {

    [self.pins enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        UIImageView *pin = obj;

        CGPoint pinCenter = [self.view convertPoint:pin.center fromView:self.scrollView];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(panningView.frame, pinCenter)) {

            CGPoint newCenterOfPanningView = [self.scrollView convertPoint:panningView.center fromView:self.view];
            panningView.center = newCenterOfPanningView;
            [panningView removeFromSuperview];
            [self.scrollView insertSubview:panningView belowSubview:pin];

            [self.resultDictionary setObject:@(panningView.tag) forKey:@(panningView.tag)];

            return;
        }
    }];

    if ([[self.resultDictionary allValues] count] == [self.items count]) [self checkResult];
}
```

And here I have problem. If I have my scroll view scrolled.  For example to `CGRectMake(480, 0.0, 362.0, 215.0)`

After adding subview, scroll view is scrolled to `CGRectMake(480, 0.0, 362.0, 215.0)` but I don't want it. I would like to scrollview stays in current possiton.

Comment: Scroll view doesn't have contentView.